# Java copy files distorting file

Tags: java, file-io, file-copying

So I am trying to copy a file to a new location this way:

```
FileReader in = new FileReader(strTempPath);
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(destTempPath);

int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1){
    out.write(c);
}

in.close();
out.close();
```

Which works fine 99% of the time.  Sometimes, if the image is rather small, <= 60x80px, the copied image comes out all distorted.  Does anyone know what might be going on here? Is it the fault of the copy function here or should I be looking elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: it depends heavily on your platform's character encoding. In most encodings, copying binary data will destroy from a few byte values to a lot of byte combinations. If the program suddenly "works" if you run it with -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1, you can be sure that at some place you tried to use readers/writers for copying binary data. ISO-8859-1 is one of the few charsets that do not destroy binary data, but depending on your locale text will be all gibberish when displayed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use a `Readers` / `Writers` to read binary data. Use a `InputStreams` / `OutputStreams` or `Channels` from the nio package (see below).

Example from [exampledepot.com](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/File2File.html):

```
try {
    // Create channel on the source
    FileChannel srcChannel = new FileInputStream("srcFilename").getChannel();

    // Create channel on the destination
    FileChannel dstChannel = new FileOutputStream("dstFilename").getChannel();

    // Copy file contents from source to destination
    dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel, 0, srcChannel.size());

    // Close the channels
    srcChannel.close();
    dstChannel.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: For that matter, don't use a `Writer` for binary data either.

Comment: Not for me, I'm still having the same issue with my files being distorted after copy. My files become almost twice the byte size!

Comment: That would be amazing - Line 153 https://github.com/johndeverall/BehaviourCoder/blob/for_aioobe/src/main/java/de/bochumuniruhr/psy/bio/behaviourcoder/BundledVLCLibsDiscoveryStrategy.java

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same issue with commons io, same size differential. It's weird, but I'll post here if I find something. The encoding is different when I check the binary, not sure why. Thanks!

Comment: "The encoding is different when I check the binary." What does that mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156589/discussion-between-aioobe-and-john-deverall).

Comment: I think its the resource filtering in the maven assembly plugin when the jar is built. So your solution above is correctly copying files that are already corrupted. So, no issue with the code above :)

Answer (score 0):

Convenience class for reading character files. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html